# Python Selenium, get elementtext xPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am stacked at the code where I need to print full text of `<li>` element

```
<h2>Product details</h2>
  <div class="content">

<ul>

    <li> <b>Paperback:</b> 288 pages</li>
    <li> <b>Publisher:</b> Pocket Books (October 1, 1998)</li>
    <li> <b>Language:</b> English</li>
    <li> <b>ISBN-10:</b> 0671027034</li>
    <li> <b>ISBN-13:</b> 978-0671027032</li>
    <li>  <b>Product Dimensions: </b>5.3 x 0.8 x 8.2 inches</li>

</ul>
```

It's actually amazon product details.I am using xpath to find class that contains text "ISBN-10":

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'ISBN-10')]").text
```

It finds element great, but my output will be:

```
ISBN-10
```

What should I use to get text that comes with ISBN-10 so my output should be:

```
ISBN-10: 0671027034
```

I don't want to search for all `<li>` elements and print [3] from list.

Comment: First of all, where is `ISBN-10` in your html posted ? Also why `class` attribute has no value ?

Comment: can you post some more html code

Comment: I have attached originally code, those empty classes were some mistakes. It's actually Amazon product details elements. I need to extract <li> element that contains "ISBN-10". So my output should be : ISBN-10: 0671027034.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following xpath and let me know if you face any issue

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='content']/ul/li[contains(.,'ISBN-10')]").text
```

Comment: Working perfectly!

Comment: Good. Glad to here :)

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is pretty close. The issue is that you are looking for `*` as the element which in XPath terms means any element. If you look at the HTML, the match you are getting is the `B` tag,

```
<b>ISBN-10:</b>
```

because that's what matches. If you just change your XPath to look for the containing `LI` tag instead of `*`, you will get what you are looking for.

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'ISBN-10')]").text
```